# new dynamic ID does not generated when call objects multiple times

Tags: katalon-studio

I have test case to insert test data using dynamic ID

below is the codes to call the POST API object 5 times, interval 8 seconds each.

but the dynamic ID is same at second execution.

how do I make the dynamic ID always generated at each execution?

```html
//Actual Kafka Topic Name
def incomingDOTopic = 'incoming-dispense-order'

//test data using dynamic Id
NewId = CustomKeywords.'swisslog.dynamicId.getUniqueId'()
println(NewId)

GlobalVariable.DynamicId = NewId

//store the dynamic ID to file
def file = new File("C:/Data Files/DynamicId.txt")
file.newWriter().withWriter { it << NewId }
println file.text

//test data with dynamic ID
def incomingDOInfo = '{"Operation":"Add","Msg":{"id":"'+GlobalVariable.DynamicId+'","locationId":"locationid"}'

for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
WebUI.delay(8)
WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Kafka/post_message', [('topic_name') : incomingDOTopic, ('message') : incomingDOInfo, ('KafkaRestName') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestName, ('KafkaRestPort'): GlobalVariable.KafkaRestPort]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found katalon has the call test case function, i implemented the loop and managed to post test data multiple times.

```html
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  
 WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('ServiceTest/Incoming'), [:], FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
 }
```